# Creating HL7 v2.3.1 A28 message in XML with ZD1 Segment, Fields & Components using Java HAPI

Tags: hl7-v2

I am using Java to create a A28 Message in HL7 XML Format. The output I want is :
XYZCompany
.
Was able to add the Non-Standard Segment ZD1 by using:
 String  aP = adt.addNonstandardSegment("ZD1");
Then added ZD1.1 Field using Terser. Now trying to add XON.1 Component:
Terser te = new Terser(adt);
String str =("XYZ Company");

str = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(str);

te.set("ZD1-1-1" , str );

But, it doesn't print XYZCompany
It prints &lt;XON.1&gt;NAVY&lt;/XON.1&gt;
.
Questions:
1) Is it right to use the Terser to set the ZD1.1 Field with XON.1 Component using this methid?
2) Do I have to use a Custom ZD1 class with set and get methods for the output (XYZ Company) as desired?
3) If a custom ZD1 class needs to be defined, how to associate it with the adt message Object so the encoding works?
.
Please let me know if you have an example Custom Z Segment creation along with its Fields and components.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you escape your string? There are no chars needing StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(str).

Comment: I want to print: <ZD1><ZD1.1><XON.1>XYZ Company</XON.1></ZD1.1></ZD1> But it prints: <ZD1>
        <ZD1.1>&lt;XON.1&gt;+NAVY+&lt;/XON.1&gt;</ZD1.1>
    </ZD1>

Comment: Does anyone know how to nest attributes in a custom segment of HL7?